# Как вставить элемент сразу в два места?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, мы создаем элемент li

```
const li = document.createElement(li);
```

а, в html есть два ul

```
<ul></ul>
<ul></ul>
```

как этот li, вставить сразу в 2 места?

Comment: никак, один элемент может быть только в одном месте. Если нужно вставить в два места, должно быть два элемента.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('ul').forEach( e => e.appendChild(document.createElement('li')) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const li = document.createElement('LI');
[...document.querySelectorAll('ul')].forEach(el => el.append(li.cloneNode()));
```

```html
<ul></ul>
<ul></ul>
```